# Ember CLI "Nothing Handled the Action"

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I'm working through [Ryan LaBouve's YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tonV3G2cPrA) on building the TodoMVC app with Ember CLI. I'm about half way through, now adding a conditional within the template. When a (todo list) item is double-clicked, it is supposed to trigger a function *editTodo* that sets a property "isEditing" to **true** and replaces the text with an input box.

The doubleClick function is not working at all. It throws the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'editTodo'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

This is the relevant template section (**todos.hbs**):

```
      <section id="main">
        <ul id="todo-list">
          {{#each todo in model itemComtroller="todo"}}
            <li {{bind-attr class="todo.isCompleted:completed todo.isEditing:editing"}}>
              {{#if todo.isEditing}}
              <input class="edit">
              {{else}}
                {{input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked=todo.isCompleted}}
                <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{todo.title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
              {{/if}}
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
      </section>
```

Here is the controller with the "editTodo" function (**todo.js**):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    editTodo: function() {
      this.set('isEditing', true);
    }
  },
  isEditing: false,
  isCompleted: function(key, value) {
    var model = this.get('model');

    if (value === undefined ) {
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    } else {
      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

I've cross-referenced my code with the video and the associated [Github repo](https://github.com/ryanlabouve/todomvc-embercli) and still can't find the cause of the problem. There are also related issues on SO, but I've not seen one quite like this. Obviously I am new to Ember.js and can use all the help I can get.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've run into a bug that was introduced in Ember 1.13.4. I'm not sure what it is, but it has to do with using an item controller and having an action in the loop. For now, you can downgrade to Ember 1.13.3 or lower to fix the issue. I will file a bug report so that this can be fixed in later versions of Ember.

Long term you won't be writing code like this. Item controllers have been completely removed in Ember 2.0, so you'll likely switch to using components for this type of situation when using Ember 2.0. For now you can practice using Ember 1.13.3.

Almost forgot:

[Code that works in 1.13.3](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wojiyakafe/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

[Same code broken in 1.13.4](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoxejitole/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

EDIT: [Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12340)

EDIT2: It seems that some behavior has changed in Ember (possibly another bug?) between 1.12.0 and 1.13.0. For some reason the actions are no longer being caught in the item controller and instead are being sent directly to the route controller. I'm not 100% sure why that is, but as a fix you can either downgrade to Ember 1.12 or move your `editTodo` action to your `todos` controller instead.

EDIT3: [Link to second Github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12347)

EDIT4: As suggested in the second bug ticket, you can also change the target of the action:

```
 <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick" target="todo"}}>{{todo.title}}</label>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I've read about the components becoming deprecated. Npm couldn't find 1.13.3, but I was able to downgrade to v1.13.1. I downgraded it on npm and bower and followed the official instructions to downgrade the app. However, I'm still having the same issue. I've upvoted your answer because it makes sense - although I still have problems. The function ("editTodo") in my controller above seems to follow a similar syntax to that in your jsbin. Really can't see why action is not being handled by that function.

Comment: In your browser's console, is `Ember.VERSION` actually equal to `1.13.1`? Depending on your development environment, there could be some kind of build/caching issue.

Comment: Actually the console shows I'm running 1.13.3 (although I installed 1.13.1). I cleaned bower and npm cache before installing.

Comment: I may have found another bug. I've updated my answer with next steps.

Comment: @GTK Thanks for your help. Npm couldn't get 1.12, and actually I checked and the tutorial I'm following uses 1.7.0 (which isn't available via npm either.). I tried the above solution (edit 4) in 1.13.3 and got an error *Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `editTodo` on <todomvc-embercli@model:todo::ember536:3> while in state root.loaded.saved.* Prior to 1.13.1 the next version available in npm is 0.2.7, so I tried the app using that version, but there were *way* too many inconsistencies. I will keep trying combinations of versions with the solutions you've provided.

Comment: I'm not sure Ember is available using NPM. You'll have to use Bower or download them on the [Ember builds page](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/tagged).